Problems with ROS install
I attempted to install ROS on Windows following the official instructions from the “Installation/Windows - ROS Wiki” page. However, the terminal returned the error: “Unable to connect to source 'https://aka.ms/ros/public'.”
I tried on three different computers, but the issue persisted.


Note that the windows install instructions for Noetic are Experimental not official.
See the listing here: http://wiki.ros.org/Installation
Microsoft has stopped supporting this installation method. There's a good complete answer here with other details and potential other options.
https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/113472/161
